# WPP tracing for linux

Tags: linux, trace, windows-wpp

I'm looking for a way to output traces to a log file in my code, which runs on linux.

I don't want to include the printing information in the binary, in every place I deploy it.

It windows, I simply used [WPP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to trace without putting the actual traces strings in my binary.

How can this by achieved in Linux?

Comment: > I don't want to include the printing information in the binary < Okay, prepare two versions of your binary, one is traceable and another is not and use conditional compilation to do them both.

Comment: @myaut It's not good enough.. I want the "release" versions, those that I deploy, to also trace data. This is what WPP is for, and this it what I want to achieve on Linux

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Linux tools in this area, so maybe there is a better system. However, since nobody else has made any good suggestions, I'll make a suggestion. (Probably not a very good suggestion, but the best I can think of right now.)

In theory, you could continue to use wpp. Wpp is simply a template system. It scans the configuration and input files to create data structures. Then it runs a template, fills in the data values it got from the scan, producing the tmh files. You could create a new set of templates that would use Linux apis instead of Windows apis, and would record the message strings in a way that works with some other log decoder system.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this question only now and would like to add my two cents to the story just for a case. Personally, I truly appreciate Windows WPP Tracing and consider it probably the best *engineering* solution for practical development troubleshooting among similar tools.

It happened I extended WPP use to Unix-like platforms twice. We wanted to use strong sides of WPP concept in general and yet use it in a multi-platform pieces of code. This was not a porting but rather a wrapper to specific WPP use we configured on Windows. One time we had a web service to perform actual WPP pre-processing on Windows; it may sound a bit insane but it worked fine and effective within the local network. A wrapper script that was executed before each compilation sent a web request, got a processed file and post-processed the generated include file to make it suitable for Unix-like platforms. The second time we implemented a simplified WPP pre-processor of our own (we found yet additional use for it - we could generate the tracing statements differently for production and unit testing, for example). This was a harsh solution: you anyway need to use some physical tracing framework behind the wrapper on non-Windows platform (well, the first time we apparently implemented our own lower level).

I do not think the Linux world has a framework comparable to WPP. Once I even thought it could be a great idea to make an open source porting project for WPP. I am not sure it would be much requested though. I said it is a great *engineering* solution. But who wants to do dirty engineering work? Open source community prefer abstract object-oriented and generic solutions, streaming and less necessity in corresponding tools (WPP requires special management tools and OS support).Ease of code writing is the today's choice.

There could be Microsoft fault (or unwillingness) in the lack of WPP popularity too. They kept it as an internal framework that came out just by a case with Windows DDK because they have to offer some logging/tracing solution for driver developers. Nobody even noticed much that WPP is well suitable for the user-space code too. And WPP pre-processor for C#, for example, has never been exposed to public at all.

Nevertheless, I still think that WPP porting to Unix/Linux work can be a challenging, interesting and maybe even useful attempt. If someone decides to lead it. :)